# Change colour of range slider

Tags: javascript, css, angular, sass, rangeslider

Recently I am installing npnslider https://npnm.github.io/NpnSlider/ .Basically I have integrated functionalities of this but the problem is how do we change colors according to the preference of this slider

Answer (score 1):

Add in your css file- and i think change range slider color

```
.slider[_ngcontent-c1] .bar[_ngcontent-c1] div.filler[_ngcontent-c1] > span[_ngcontent-c1] {
    background: #000 !important;
}

.slider[_ngcontent-c1] .bar[_ngcontent-c1] > span.left-handle[_ngcontent-c1], .slider[_ngcontent-c1] .bar[_ngcontent-c1] > span.right-handle[_ngcontent-c1] {
    background: white !important;
    border-color: red !important;
}

.slider[_ngcontent-c1] .bar[_ngcontent-c1] {
    background: #f5f5f5 !important;
}

.slider[_ngcontent-c1] .bar[_ngcontent-c1] > span.left-handle[_ngcontent-c1] .handle-tooltip[_ngcontent-c1], .slider[_ngcontent-c1] .bar[_ngcontent-c1] > span.right-handle[_ngcontent-c1] .handle-tooltip[_ngcontent-c1] {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    border-color: black !important;
}

.slider[_ngcontent-c1] .bar[_ngcontent-c1] > span.left-handle[_ngcontent-c1] .handle-tooltip[_ngcontent-c1]:before, .slider[_ngcontent-c1] .bar[_ngcontent-c1] > span.right-handle[_ngcontent-c1] .handle-tooltip[_ngcontent-c1]:before {
    border-top-color: #000;
}

.slider[_ngcontent-c1] .bar[_ngcontent-c1] > span.left-handle[_ngcontent-c1] .handle-tooltip[_ngcontent-c1]:after, .slider[_ngcontent-c1] .bar[_ngcontent-c1] > span.right-handle[_ngcontent-c1] .handle-tooltip[_ngcontent-c1]:after {
    border-top-color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer this works for me

```
 .slider .bar div.filler > span {
        background: rebeccapurple !important;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Give it a class with background color of your choice.

```
<npn-slider class='custom-class' [multiRange]="false" [min]="2006" [max]="2020" [minSelected]="2010"></npn-slider>
</div>

<style>
.custom-class {
  background: 'yourcolor';
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I  did have the same problem, after some time reading and searching about It, I have a solution for It, I did found the `::ng-deep` css property, It preceded for a custom class in npn-slider selector help us to change all css on It and any other component, this is my css file:

```
.my-slider::ng-deep .slider .bar > span.left-handle {
  background: #dcb2b2 !important;
  border: 7px solid #b35a57 !important;
}

.my-slider::ng-deep .slider .bar > span.right-handle {
  background: #dcb2b2 !important;
  border: 7px solid #b35a57 !important;
}

.my-slider::ng-deep .slider .bar div.filler > span {
  background: #dcb2b2 !important;
}

.my-slider::ng-deep .slider .bar > span.left-handle .handle-tooltip {
  color: #b35757 !important;
  background: #ebd2d2 !important;
  border: 1px solid #c37a7a !important;
}

.my-slider::ng-deep .slider .bar > span.left-handle .handle-tooltip:after {
  border-top-color: #ebd2d2 !important;
}

.my-slider::ng-deep .slider .bar > span.right-handle .handle-tooltip {
  color: #b35757 !important;
  background: #ebd2d2 !important;
  border: 1px solid #c37a7a !important;
}

.my-slider::ng-deep .slider .bar > span.right-handle .handle-tooltip:after {
  border-top-color: #ebd2d2 !important;
}

.my-slider::ng-deep .slider .bar div.filler > div.step-indicators > span {
  background: #b35757 !important;
}
```

And this is my html

```
<npn-slider  class="my-slider" [min]="1000" [max]="5000" (onChange)="onSliderChange($event)" [step]="500" [showStepIndicator]="true"></npn-slider>
```

At this [link](https://github.com/npnm/NpnSlider/blob/master/projects/npn-slider/src/lib/npn-slider.component.css) you can find the style routes or how I did do this, exploring with browser inspector XD.

At the last, is very important that you use `!important` in each css property, on the contrary the changes aren't work for you.

My result was:

[image]